# Sequence of events with vanishing individual probability and a finite sum condition leads to P($A_n$ i.o)=0

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I am trying to show that if $A_n$ is a sequence of events satisfying $P(A_n)\to 0$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(A_n^c\cap A_{n+1})<\infty$ implies that $P(A_n \ i.o.)=0$ (i.o. means infinitely often).

My rough idea is that $P(A_n)\to0$ means $A_n^c$ converges almost surely to the entire sample space of possibilities -- call the latter $\Omega$. So $P(A_n^c\cap A_{n+1})\to P(\Omega \cap A_{n+1})=P(A_{n+1})$. Then we have $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(A_{n+1})<\infty$ so $P(A_n\ i.o.)=0$ by a Borel-Cantelli lemma.

I would be grateful for input as whether this idea works. In particular, I'm not sure if this notion of events converging almost surely to sets is well-defined.

Thanks a bunch in advance!

Comment: Thjanks! Corrected it

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/942600/) for a generalization of the Borel Cantelli lemma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conclusion is wrong. Here is a counter example.

Suppose $A_1\supset A_2\supset \cdots\supset A_n\cdots$, and $P(A_n)=1/n$. Then $A_n^c\cap A_{n+1}=\varnothing$ and $P(A_n^c\cap A_{n+1})=0$. But 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(A_n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{n}=\infty
$$
Thus $P(A_n\ i.o.)\ne0$.

Comment: What are the random variables associated with your events? If we define $X_n$ to be a discrete uniform random variable with possibilities $P(X_n=j)=1/n$ for $j=1,2,...,n$ and let the $X_n$ be pairwise independent, then define $A_n=P(X_n=n)$, then we actually get $P(A_n^c \cap A_{n+1})=(1-1/n)(1/(n+1)).$ If we take this term to be summands, we get an infinite sum.

So you're thinking the $A_n$s are not independent events (i.e. $A_n$ and $A_{n+1}$ are mutually exclusive, such that $P(A_n)=1/n$. I'm having trouble constructing such events. Could you be more explicit with the random variables

Comment: that are being used in your $A_n$? Thanks for your response!

Comment: @manofbear: Let $U$ be uniform $[0,1]$ and define $A_n$ to be the event that $U$ lands in $[0,1/n]$.

Comment: Theoretically $P(A_n)=1/n$ exist without doubt. Sometimes you don't always need concrete one as long as it makes perfect sense.  Your example is not good since they are not nested, i.e. $A_{n+1}\subset A_n$.  For nested events, I think they are not independent. You can think of something like $A_n=P(X_n<n)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot both of you guys!